# single list with multiple values and missing values to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list:

```
 data=['ip: 1.2.3.9',
 'port: 80',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'banner: HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\x0d\\x0a',
 'service: http',
 'ip: 2.3.19.7',
 'port: 23',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'banner: xff\\xfb\\x03',
 'service: unknown',
 'ip: 21.17.28.15',
 'port: 8080',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'service: title',
 'ip: 3.17.8.15',
 'port: 8080',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'service: title']
```

The list has an order, so each ip, port, protocol, state, banner, and service are a row. This should be the first row: 'ip: 1.2.3.9','port: 80', 'protocol: tcp', 'state:open', 'banner: HTTP/1.1 200 OK\x0d\x0a', service: http'. However, sometimes, I have only ip, port, protocol, state, service, and no banner, or any other missing value is possible. I want to convert this to a dataframe, and I have tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
col= ['ip', 'port', 'protocol','state','banner','service']
df = pd.DataFrame([data[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(data), 6)], columns=col)
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
Out[75]: 
                ip           port       protocol           state  \
0      ip: 1.2.3.9       port: 80  protocol: tcp      state:open   
1     ip: 2.3.19.7       port: 23  protocol: tcp      state:open   
2  ip: 21.17.28.15     port: 8080  protocol: tcp      state:open   
3       port: 8080  protocol: tcp     state:open  service: title   

                            banner           service  
0  banner: HTTP/1.1 200 OK\x0d\x0a     service: http  
1              banner: xff\xfb\x03  service: unknown  
2                   service: title     ip: 3.17.8.15  
3                             None              None
```

As you can see in the second row banner should be empty and service is not in the right column, and the IP that should be in the next row is where the service value should be. The values are being stored continuously, so how can I check and make sure that each value is in its respective column?. I am not a pandas expert, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the same concept as sammywemmy's answer by creating dictionaries but does not use the default_dict or itertools libraries.  It creates a dictionary for each set of records, when it gets to a key that is already in the dictionary it appends the dictionary to a list and restarts the creation.

```
data=['ip: 1.2.3.9',
 'port: 80',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'banner: HTTP/1.1 200 OK\\x0d\\x0a',
 'service: http',
 'ip: 2.3.19.7',
 'port: 23',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'banner: xff\\xfb\\x03',
 'service: unknown',
 'ip: 21.17.28.15',
 'port: 8080',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'service: title',
 'ip: 3.17.8.15',
 'port: 8080',
 'protocol: tcp',
 'state:open',
 'service: title']

dict_list = []
append_dict = {}
for item in data:
    key, value = item.split(':')
    value = value.strip()
    if key not in append_dict.keys():
        append_dict[key]=value
    else:
        dict_list.append(append_dict)
        append_dict = {}
        append_dict[key]=value
dict_list.append(append_dict)

## create dataframe with list of dictionaries.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)

print(df.head())

            ip  port protocol state                   banner  service
0      1.2.3.9    80      tcp  open  HTTP/1.1 200 OK\x0d\x0a     http
1     2.3.19.7    23      tcp  open              xff\xfb\x03  unknown
2  21.17.28.15  8080      tcp  open                      NaN    title
3    3.17.8.15  8080      tcp  open                      NaN    title
```

Comment: urs has better coverage. +1

Comment: Thanks @jawsen, the approach works perfectly! I just had to adjust the key, value = item.split(':') to key, value = item.split('|'), since sometimes the colon appears in the content of the banner too :)